# XMPP presence for same JID, different resource

Tags: php, xmpp, chat

I have developed my own [XMPP PHP library](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php) which I use to communicate with external XMPP server which is not mine.

After initial auth I am sending empty presence stanza `<presence/>`.

I have an open socket socket connection to that server which is fetching server response, if any.

I have also implemented my library within a corporate app. I have set the app resource to be one thing, and app running from terminal to other, so I can distinguish between the two.

What I've noticed though if I have both running in parallel, I am constantly getting these responses:

```
<presence from="a@b.com/app" to="a@b.com/terminal"/>
<presence type="unavailable" from="a@b.com/app" to="a@b.com/terminal"/>
```

These never seem to stop unless I kill one of the two running instances. I am not sending any request which would require server to respond with unavailable presence so I'm not quite sure what is happening here and how can I resolve it?